# BlueJ Unit Test fails despite equality holding

Tags: java, unit-testing, bluej

Unit test fails yet `biComplexNumber1.equals(biComplexNumber2)` holds true.

Unit test:

```
 public void simpleTest(){
    BicomplexNumber b1 = new BicomplexNumber(1,2,3,4);
    BicomplexNumber b2 = new BicomplexNumber(1,2,3,4);
    assertEquals("Simple Test", b1, b2);
}
```

Equality check

```
public boolean equals(BicomplexNumber bicomplexObj) 
{
    if(bicomplexObj == this) return true;
    if(bicomplexObj.getA() != this.getA()) return false;
    if(bicomplexObj.getB() != this.getB()) return false;
    if(bicomplexObj.getC() != this.getC()) return false;
    if(bicomplexObj.getD() != this.getD()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

The equality check seems to be correct when I would like it too. But I have included it anyway.

Comment: You're not overriding `equals(Object)`, which is the method that will be called by `assertEquals`.

Comment: I changed object to BicomplexNumber in the method call because I need to use methods of BicomplexNumber in order to check for equality.. How can I do this for a generic object being passed into the method?

Comment: You have to take an `Object` parameter, check if it is a `BicomplexNumber`, and cast. See the question linked in my previous comment.

Comment: @AndyTurner while this is a bad practice it should work. If `equals` is called with `BicomplexNumber` as an actual parameter, it should bind to that implementation. If it's called with a non matching type, the inherited `equals(Object)` should be called.

Comment: @AndréStannek "it should work" it doesn't, because `assertEquals(Object, Object)` invokes `equals(Object)`. You can define the `equals(BicomplexNumber)`, sure, you just can't expect it to be used in place of the former.

Comment: I changed the parameter to an Object, and used the approach in the dupe. The unit test that I showed now works. Additionally the unit test for the thing I was already testing also passed! Thank you kind sir!

Comment: @AndyTurner nevermind, I didn't consider the hard cast to `Obect` during JUnit processing.